# How to get URL, that browser uses for CSP

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, content-security-policy

I'm creating a script, that embed iframe with my site to client's site, but I want to limit access to this feature.

I added 2 headers to the server responses

> ```
> Content-Security-Policy: "frame-ancestors: example.com"
> X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM example.com
> ```

It works, but `X-Frame-Options` doesn't support multiple domains, so I added a GET-param to the iframe URLs, that contain frame ancestor URL

And when `http://example.net` requests `mysite.com/embed/?from=http://example.net` I check the whitelist and send this domain in headers

My problem is obtaining a real page origin, that browser uses to compare with the headers.
I tried `location.origin` and `document.referrer` but both return wrong values when I request iframe from iframe.

For example http://jsbin.com. I can't find way to obtain real URL in sandboxed code, it's always `http://null.jsbin.com`. But for `Content-Security-Policy` a browser uses `http://jsbin.com/`

Comment: What gives you the impression that it doesn't use `http://null.jsbin.com`?

Comment: I get a browser error `Refused to display 'http://example.com/embed&from=http%3A%2F%2Fnull.jsbin.com%2Frunner' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self' http://null.jsbin.com".`

Comment: “An ancestor” is any frame above the page you’re trying to load, not just the immediate parent.